# Google Earth API getBalloonHtmlUnsafe suppress balloon while panning

Tags: javascript, api, kml, pan, balloon

If I click on a polygon and then pan, a balloon will pop up. When I'm not getting BalloonHtmlUnsafe this isn't a problem. Is there a way to modify my code to suppress the balloon popup when I pan? I'm new to javascript so please provide an example if possible.

I am fetching kml that contains html balloons. Here is the event listener I am using:

```
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', function(event) {
  var obj = event.getTarget();
  if (obj.getType() === 'KmlPlacemark'){
  event.preventDefault();
  var placemark = obj;
  var placemark_desc_active = placemark.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe();
  var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('[CDATA]');
  balloon.setContentString(placemark_desc_active);
        balloon.setMaxWidth(500);
        balloon.setMaxHeight(500);
  ge.setBalloon(balloon); }});
```

Thanks for any help